# iBooks sharing with iOS Application

Tags: ios, objective-c, sharing, ibooks

I have a question about iBooks sharing.

I want to open a book from iBooks with my iOS Application. To create this I have specified content type:

```
<dict>
    <key>CFBundleTypeName</key>
    <string>All Files</string>
    <key>LSHandlerRank</key>
    <string>Alternate</string>
    <key>LSItemContentTypes</key>
    <array>
        <string>public.calendar-event</string>
        <string>public.database</string>
        <string>public.executable</string>
        <string>public.data</string>
        <string>public.content </string>
        <string>public.item</string>
    </array>
</dict>
```

As far as I understand, this should contain all available files. Nevertheless, when I am sharing a document from iBooks, my application selection is not shown:https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B6ycu14tT4SGeExGZV9Ca3ZJeEk/view?usp=sharing

Where is the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Those content types are used when an app is trying to directly open a file using a UIDocumentInteractionController ([Document Interaction Programming Topics for iOS](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/DocumentInteraction_TopicsForIOS/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010409-SW1))

What iBooks is showing is a share dialog, and if you want to appear there, your only option might be using an app extension ([App Extension Programming Guide](http://Document%20Interaction%20Programming%20Topics%20for%20iOS))

In any case, you won't be getting much out of it, since what iBooks shares it's just title/author of the book and iTunes link if bought from there, not the actual book (you know, DRM and stuff...)

Comment: So, that means that there is no way to open book from iBooks with anoter app?

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE 2019:

You can open iBooks to a specific book now by including the assetid of the book you want to open. Example:

```
ibooks://assetid/1396541327
```

Details available on the Apple.com website - https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT202929